# Why is my layout not showing in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[As you can see, I have a text view and a button but none of it is showing on the device. The device is empty, so I'm wondering how can I get these things to show? Nothing so far has been working, I already tried clicking on the magic wand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrlmC.png)

Comment: please post your ```res > layout > activity_main.xml``` along with ```java > MainActivity.java``` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the  problems, I Encountered while working in android. 
You have to edit your res/values/styles.xml file

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Steps are as following:
Go to res/values/
open styles.xml

change from -> style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

change to -> style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

(Just prepend "Base." to "Theme".)

Save the file and check Preview now.

Preview will Work Perfeclty now.